# Extra dot in header

Tags: header-footer

I tried to deal with dots/symbol of paragraph in headers, tableofcontent and in names of sections directly.

Everything is perfect with chapters, tableofcontent, subsections, names of sections.

But I found an extra dot in header on the even pages. Screenshot is here. It's awful.

I tried my best... But now I want to ask your help. Please remove this dot without changing another things.

```
   %document information
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

% packages
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textsection\arabic{section}.}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead [CE] {\nouppercase{\slshape \large \rightmark}}
\fancyhead [CO] {\nouppercase{\slshape \large \leftmark}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{eh eh}
\section{omg}

\chapter{oh no}
\section{lmao}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace in your preamble

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\textsection\thesection}{1em}{}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
```

with

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{²textsection\thesection.}{1em}{}
```

Your last command has as result that cross references to section will add a dot after the section number.

**Added:*

Here is code that contains a solution for the table of contents

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
% packages
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textsection\arabic{section}}
\titlecontents{section}[2.7em]{\addvspace{0.5ex}}%
 {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{1.25em}\hskip0.8em}%numbered
 {}%numberless%
 {\enspace\titlerule*[0.7pc]{.}\contentspage}%

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead [CE] {\nouppercase{\slshape \large \rightmark}}
\fancyhead [CO] {\nouppercase{\slshape \large \leftmark}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{eh eh}
\section{omg}

\chapter{oh no}
\section{lmao}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But here table of content is without this important dot.

Comment: You can format the table of contents, say, with `titletoc`, since you use `titlesec`.

Comment: @Dida: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: To answer your question: yes. See the updated code.

Comment: Yes, I see. It works. But there is another problem: \Snumber in TOC has black color, but my hyperref wants blue...

Comment: \textcolor{darkblue}{\tableofcontents} helps, but I think it is unbeatiful.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want:does it have to be coloured or black?

Comment: my table of content is of blue color because of hyperref. Your solution adds to it black unclickable "\S". But I want it to be colored and clickable, if it is possible.

Comment: What is clickable is the section title. You can add colour to the section label, or set `linkcolor` to`black`.